# In gvim on windows C-] does not work (but C left mouse works)

Tags: windows, vim, gvim, ctags

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> in gVim on Windows does not work for me.  I know that the tags file is loaded since the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd> works as intended.  I did not find anything of help in [Browsing programs with tags](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Browsing_programs_with_tags).

Can I add something in .vimrc to repair it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put

```
nmap <C-\> :exe 'tag ' . expand('<cword>')<CR>
nmap g<C-\> :exe 'tjump ' . expand('<cword>')<CR>
```

in your `%HOME%\_vimrc` (IIRC vim does not use `%USERPROFILE%` but needs `%HOME%`)

I chose `<C-\>`, because it's the neighbouring key, but choose whatever replacement key combination you want.